# To bring the custom view to bottom of the layout without changing the parameters of OnDraw?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom drawing drawn on a custom view .I would like to bring this view to the bottom half of the screen without changing the co-ordinates of the ondraw function. I know this can be done but I am not able to do it. Please assist me.

This is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <your.com.learn.game
            android:id="@+id/game1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

game view code:

```
public class game extends View{
    private Bitmap image;
    private Paint paint;
    private int x=0;private int baseY = 250;

    public game(Context context,AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);

        //TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        //LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.example,this);

        //this.inflate(context, R.layout.example, null);
        image=Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        paint =new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(90, baseY,200,baseY, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(125,baseY,125,baseY-100,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(110,baseY,125,baseY-15,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(140,baseY,125,baseY-15,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(125,baseY-100,175,baseY-100,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(125,baseY-85,140,baseY-100,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(175,baseY-100,175,baseY-75,paint);
        canvas.drawOval(new RectF(170,(baseY-75),10,12),paint);
        canvas.drawOval(new RectF(170,baseY-65,15,25), paint);
        canvas.drawLine(160,baseY-65,170,baseY-60,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(183,baseY-60,193,baseY-65,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(165,baseY-30,170,baseY-45,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(183,baseY-45,193,baseY-30,paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        final int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        boolean resizeWidth = widthSpecMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;
        boolean resizeHeight = heightSpecMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;
    }

    public void update()
    {
         if(x < 200)
                x++;
            else
                x=0;
    }
}
```

Logcat when game view is added to nested Scrollview(as described by Sam below) :

```
07-05 18:53:09.638: W/dalvikvm(858): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{your.com.learn/your.com.learn.LearningActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at your.com.learn.LearningActivity.onCreate(LearningActivity.java:42) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611) 
07-05 18:53:09.649: E/AndroidRuntime(858): ... 11 more


public class LearningActivity extends Activity  {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private game g;



int i=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //For my button class
    /*
    MyButton myb = (MyButton)findViewById(R.id.mybutton1);
    myb.setText("Hello Students");
    myb.setTextSize(40);
   **/

    //For custom view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //RelativeLayout r=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    g=new game(this,null);
    ViewGroup vgroup=(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main);
     vgroup.addView(g);
    Thread mythread=new Thread(new UpdateThread());
    mythread.start();


}


public Handler updatehandler=new Handler(){
    /** Gets called on every message that is received */
    // @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       // g.update();

        g.invalidate();
         super.handleMessage(msg);

    }
};






public class UpdateThread implements Runnable
{

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true){
            //calling the handler
            LearningActivity.this.updatehandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rewrite**

I haven't done much drawing on the canvas myself, but here is a way to make your current class work:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <org.whatever.example.game
        android:id="@+id/game1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I tried nesting your Game View in another View (say a ScrollView), it wouldn't draw anything. I don't know why at this time, however the above code will get you moving the your next step. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi,I tried the above one where I replaced the TextView to my game view layout and it is not coming...Infact it shows an exception...could this be I havent include onMeasure function in my game view...

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath I assume it is caused somewhere in your game view code... Please post the logcat and any relevant code, so that I can see what is happening.

Comment: There is no error so there is nothing to be published from logcat...the code is provided above...I added the onMeasure to check if it makes a difference but it doesn't

Comment: Well there is an error when I add the game view inside nested scroll view..the log cat is added above.

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath `at your.com.learn.LearningActivity.onCreate(LearningActivity.java:42)` The Logcat tells us that you have a NullPointerException in LearnActivity.onCreate() line 42. Often this is from `findViewById(R.id.game1)` when `game1` doesn't exit in the XML. (I updated my answer to reflect this, double check your XML and line 42). Also you may be drawing your game View off of the screen, what happens when you set `baseY = 0`?

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Initially I had issues even with the re edited layout but as you mentionbed  I checked line number 42 and its ViewGroup vgroup=(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main); vgroup.addView(g);//So I removed this and now the pic appears below the screen .For time being that would keep me going......

Answer (score 0):

try changing your layout for this one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <your.com.learn.game
            android:id="@+id/game1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the `alingparentbottom` atribute will set your custom view to the bottom.

Comment: could you post the code wherever you are inflating this layout? maybe you are changing something there.